# My DROPDOWN menu in html css bootstrap not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For some reason, my dropdown in my FORM is not working; nothing happens when it is clicked. I also find it strange because I copied this code from somewhere else, and it isn't working. I have checked for typos multiple times but came up with nothing.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

        <title>My Awesome Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            body,
            html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                background: #60a3bc !important;
            }

            .user_card {
                height: 430px;
                width: 350px;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                background: #f39c12;
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 1px;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                border-radius: 5px;

            }

            .brand_logo_container {
                position: absolute;
                height: 170px;
                width: 170px;
                top: -75px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: #60a3bc;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .brand_logo {
                height: 150px;
                width: 150px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 2px solid white;
            }

            .form_container {
                margin-top: 5px;
            }

            .login_btn {
                width: 100%;
                background: #c0392b !important;
                color: white !important;
            }

            .login_btn:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }

            .login_container {
                padding: 0 2rem;
            }

            .input-group-text {
                background: #c0392b !important;
                color: white !important;
                border: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
            }

            .input_user,
            .input_pass:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }

            .custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
                background-color: #c0392b !important;
            }




        </style>
    </head>
    <!--Coded with love by Mutiullah Samim-->

    <body>
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="user_card">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                        <form>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" name="" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" name="" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="email.">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" name="" class="form-control input_pass" value="" placeholder="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-flag"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Country.
                                </button>





    ***

/*HERE IS THE PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEMPROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM PROBLEM*/
------------------------------------------------------------------------

***
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-genderless"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Gender
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Male</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Female</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                <button type="button" name="button" class="btn login_btn">Sign Up</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                            Already have an account? <a href="#" class="ml-2">Login.</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery (two different versions no less) and BS CSS twice? What errors are you getting in the console, because I'm sure there are errors there

Answer (score 0):

According to the Bootstrap introduction, you will need to include the the popper.js script for some bootstrap feature like [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#overview), tooltip, etc. to work.
Here is the script you need to include:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

On a side note, you seem to have imported the jQuery script twice, please consider removing one of them.